# SQL Error [909] [42000]: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve report from postgreSQL database to Oracle data base, but it isn't working as I thought. I tried to find related tables in Oracle database and found them as SOR tables, some data is in Datamarts.

SQL Error [909] [42000]: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

SQL statement that works just fine in postgreSQL:

```
`SELECT
    'loan' as product, 
   count(cc.id), 
   cc."type", 
   cc.topic, 
   cc.direction, 
   TRIM(cc.subject) AS subject,
   case when EXISTS (SELECT caf.communication_id
    FROM serp_bigmoney_lv.comm_attachment_files caf where cc.id = caf.communication_id) then 
'yes' 
    else 'no' end as file_attached, 
   concat(us."name",' ',us.surname) as user_name, 
   cc.createdat::date
from erp_bigmoney_lv.comm_communication cc
left join erp_bigmoney_lv.erp_users us on us.user_id = cc.created_by
where cc."type" = 'note' 
GROUP BY cc.createdat::date, user_name, file_attached, cc.direction, cc.topic, cc."type", 
product, cc.subject`
```

Comment: I _think_ Oracle's concat takes only 2 arguments. I'd try `us."name" || ' ' || us.surname` instead, the ANSI SQL way!

Comment: what is this '::date'? Oracle has no such syntax. If you're sending this to Oracle db, it will surely fail.

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT function only accept two arguments use || to concatenate the fields like:

```
FIELD_1 || ‘ ‘ || FIELD_2
```